# Windows Update 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a 2008R2 RDS server with Automatic Updates set to notify.  Somewhere along the way the box got checked for "Allow all users to update this computer", which isn't what I want.  However, it's done.

Updates ran a few weeks ago and installed.  Is there a way to determine which user kicked off the update procedure?  I see dates and times in the log, but it only refers to the WU system account and not the original user.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows Update uses a system account to install when configured to do so automatically. You may see entries under a user account if the updates were installed manually.

Comment: You might at least be able correlate with the Security log to determine who was logged in while the updates started... that should at least get you a list of suspects. Not that I necessarily agree that this witch hunt is worth your time.

Comment: I agree Ryan.  Mainly the reason to know was to if it's someone who should know better to document the changes, I'd remind them.  Otherwise it's futile.